# MariaDB config optimization

Tags: mysql, debian

So i think i really messed up my configuration file for mariadb. Im using a dedicated server for apache2 and mysql. I do not know if the server response time is caused by mysql taking too long to respond to a query or if its the code itself. I already tried some config generators but i dont feel like they work. Here are the dedicated servers specs:

`Intel C2750
 32 GB RAM
 256 GB SSD`

```
#
# These groups are read by MariaDB server.
# Use it for options that only the server (but not clients) should see
#
# See the examples of server my.cnf files in /usr/share/mysql/
#

# this is read by the standalone daemon and embedded servers
[server]

# this is only for the mysqld standalone daemon
[mysqld]

#
# * Basic Settings
#
user        = mysql
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port        = 3306
basedir     = /usr
datadir     = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir      = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking
# Skip reverse DNS lookup of clients
skip-name-resolve
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
# bind-address      = 127.0.0.1

#
# * Fine Tuning
#
key_buffer_size     = 5048M
key-buffer-size     = 32M
max_allowed_packet  = 2024M
max-allowed-packet  = 16M 
max-connect-errors  = 1000000
thread_stack        = 1024K
thread_cache_size       = 30
# This replaces the startup script and checks MyISAM tables if needed
# the first time they are touched
myisam_recover_options  = BACKUP
max_connections        = 500
table_cache            = 100
table_open_cache = 3000
table_definition_cache = 9000
join_buffer_size = 300K
performance_schema = ON

#thread_concurrency     = 10
max_user_connections    = 455
#
# * Query Cache Configuration
#
query_cache_limit   = 1048M
query_cache_size    = 0
query_cache_type    = 0

slow-query-log = 1
slow-query-log-file = /var/lib/mysql/mysql-slow.log
long_query_time = 1
#
# * Logging and Replication
#
# Both location gets rotated by the cronjob.
# Be aware that this log type is a performance killer.
# As of 5.1 you can enable the log at runtime!
#general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
#general_log             = 1
#
# Error log - should be very few entries.
#
log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
#
# Enable the slow query log to see queries with especially long duration
#slow_query_log_file    = /var/log/mysql/mariadb-slow.log
#long_query_time = 10
#log_slow_rate_limit    = 1000
#log_slow_verbosity = query_plan
#log-queries-not-using-indexes
#
# The following can be used as easy to replay backup logs or for replication.
# note: if you are setting up a replication slave, see README.Debian about
#       other settings you may need to change.
#server-id      = 1
#log_bin            = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
expire_logs_days    = 10
max_binlog_size   = 100M
#binlog_do_db       = include_database_name
#binlog_ignore_db   = exclude_database_name

#
# * InnoDB
#
# InnoDB is enabled by default with a 10MB datafile in /var/lib/mysql/.
# Read the manual for more InnoDB related options. There are many!
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 15G
#innodb_s_lock_spin_rounds = 120
#innodb_thread_concurrency = 0
innodb_log_file_size = 3G
innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 25

tmp-table-size                 = 32M
max-heap-table-size            = 32M
query-cache-type               = 0
query-cache-size               = 0
max-connections                = 500
thread-cache-size              = 50
open-files-limit               = 65535
table-definition-cache         = 4096
table-open-cache               = 100
innodb-flush-method            = O_DIRECT
innodb-log-files-in-group      = 2
innodb-log-file-size           = 512M
innodb-flush-log-at-trx-commit = 2
innodb-file-per-table          = 1
innodb-buffer-pool-size        = 26G

#innodb_buffer_size = 256M
#
# * Security Features
#
# Read the manual, too, if you want chroot!
# chroot = /var/lib/mysql/
#
# For generating SSL certificates you can use for example the GUI tool "tinyca".
#
# ssl-ca=/etc/mysql/cacert.pem
# ssl-cert=/etc/mysql/server-cert.pem
# ssl-key=/etc/mysql/server-key.pem
#
# Accept only connections using the latest and most secure TLS protocol version.
# ..when MariaDB is compiled with OpenSSL:
# ssl-cipher=TLSv1.2
# ..when MariaDB is compiled with YaSSL (default in Debian):
# ssl=on

#
# * Character sets
#
# MySQL/MariaDB default is Latin1, but in Debian we rather default to the full
# utf8 4-byte character set. See also client.cnf
#
character-set-server  = utf8mb4
collation-server      = utf8mb4_general_ci

#
# * Unix socket authentication plugin is built-in since 10.0.22-6
#
# Needed so the root database user can authenticate without a password but
# only when running as the unix root user.
#
# Also available for other users if required.
# See https://mariadb.com/kb/en/unix_socket-authentication-plugin/

# this is only for embedded server
[embedded]

# This group is only read by MariaDB servers, not by MySQL.
# If you use the same .cnf file for MySQL and MariaDB,
# you can put MariaDB-only options here
[mariadb]

# This group is only read by MariaDB-10.1 servers.
# If you use the same .cnf file for MariaDB of different versions,
# use this group for options that older servers don't understand
[mariadb-10.1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that if you specify an option more than once, only the *last* setting for that option takes effect. You have quite a few repeats, which just causes confusion about which value is really in effect.

I suggest you do the following:

- Sort the lines in your my.cnf **alphabetically** to find the duplicates (I mean the lines within the `[mysqld]` section).
- Pick which value you really want to be in effect, and remove the other lines with superfluous settings for the same option.
- Remove option lines where you set the option to its default anyway.
- Remove option lines for which you don't have a specific reason to choose a value that is not the default.

I notice you have:

```
innodb-buffer-pool-size        = 26G
```

This is 81% of your 32G RAM. Assume the buffer pool uses at least 10% extra, so it really uses 28.6G. So you have only 3.4G for all other RAM needs on your server, including MySQL, Apache, other processes, and the OS itself.

MySQL has other uses of RAM besides the buffer pool, especially per connection, and you allow up to 500 connections.

You also run Apache on the same server, and naturally any web apps run by Apache. They will each use RAM too, and I can't predict how much because it depends entirely on your application code. Apache allows multiple concurrent requests to run, so you may have dozens or hundreds of copies of the web app handling requests.

So I'm wondering if you're just using too much RAM, and forcing the server to use swap space on disk. This is a performance killer for any server, because disk (even SSD) is orders of magnitude slower than RAM.

You should monitor memory use with `top` or `free` or `vmstat`. If you see RAM running out and the system using swap, you should try to reduce the allocation of RAM, or put limits on the number of connections or the number of Apache requests. You could also install more RAM, or even move Apache to a second dedicated server.

Comment: @eptun Please POST in original question,  current complete my.cnf/ini, php.ini (if used)
Text results of: 
A) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; 
B) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES;
C) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
D) SELECT name, count FROM information_schema.innodb_metrics ORDER BY name; 
Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
E) htop   OR  top for most active apps
F) ulimit -a       for a linux/unix list of limits, 
G) MySQLTuner.com  entire report